# Likelihood Ratio Test of exp(λ) distribution with multiple samples

Tags: probability, random-variables, hypothesis-testing, exponential-distribution

I'm probably really overcomplicating things but I want to specify the likelihood ratio test with significance level $\alpha = 0.05$

I have three random samples (sample sizes: $n_1, n_2$ and $n_3$), with sample means $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$, respectively. $X_i$ has an $\exp(\mu_1)$ distribution, $Y_i$ has an $\exp(\mu_2)$ distribution, and $Z_i$ has an $\exp(\mu_3)$ distribution.

I understand how to do it for one random sample but I don't understand how to approach it for three samples.

MLE of $\lambda$ is the reciprocal of the sample mean.
H0 :$\mu_1=\mu_2 =\mu_3$ versus H1 : H0 is not true.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The method is the same. Given the sample $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n_1},y_1,\ldots,y_{n_2},z_1,\ldots,z_{n_3})$ write down the likelihood function $L(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)=\prod_{i=1}^{n_1}f_{X_1}(x_i)\prod_{i=1}^{n_2}f_{Y_i}(y_i)\prod_{i=1}^{n_3}f_Z(z_i)$. Form the likelihood ratio statistic $\Lambda=\frac{\sup_{H_0}L(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)}{\sup_{H_o\cup H_1}L(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)}$ and remember to reject $H_0$ for small values of $\Lambda$. So start by finding the maximum likelihood estimate of $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)$ under $H_0$ and under $H_0\cup H_1$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent and have the same mean, then the sum $T=X+Y+Z$ is Gamma distributed with $\alpha=3$ and $\beta=\lambda$. So, under the zero hypothesis, the sum is a Gamma random variable; then, you use a test (for instance, a qq plot or a histogram) to see if the data match a Gamma random variable with the required confidence.